# Multiple JBoss Web Application Deployment Descriptor with same resources

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, web-deployment

I have an ear including several war deployed on jboss as 7.1.1.
Each war have a custom JBoss Web Application Deployment Descriptor (jboss-web.xml) declaring the context-root and several jndi datasources all shared between the different web-apps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>

<context-root>${app.name}</context-root>

<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>${datasource}</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <jndi-name>java:/TenantDS</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>

<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>${shared.datasource}</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <jndi-name>java:/CustomerDS</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>

[...]
</jboss-web>
```

If I add another war with a jboss-web.xml file declaring only the first datasource (because it's the only one used by this war) then none of remaining war is able to reach the missing datasource anymore.

How a webapp specific deployment descriptor can have such a behavior ? And so, what is wrong in this config ? where should the datasource be declared ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have declared datasource in web.xml? You have to have it in jboss-web.xml and web.xml in each war application.

Comment: in the web.xml i've the used datasource and it's working fine, but i need to add the unused one in the jboss-web.xml (but not the web.xml), otherwise the DS is not reachable by any other war